# Invoke Javascript Test Click in Web Browser control

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

I'm trying to invoke a JS script that simulates a click on an element in the WebBrowser Control.

I'm currently doing this:

```
webBrowser2.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                    HtmlElement testScript = webBrowser2.Document.CreateElement("script");
                    IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)testScript.DomElement;
                    element.text = "function simulate(g,c){var e=extend(defaultOptions,arguments[2]||{});var b,f=null;for(var d in eventMatchers){if(eventMatchers[d].test(c)){f=d;break}}if(!f){throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported')}if(document.createEvent){b=document.createEvent(f);if(f=='HTMLEvents'){b.initEvent(c,e.bubbles,e.cancelable)}else{b.initMouseEvent(c,e.bubbles,e.cancelable,document.defaultView,e.button,e.pointerX,e.pointerY,e.pointerX,e.pointerY,e.ctrlKey,e.altKey,e.shiftKey,e.metaKey,e.button,g)}g.dispatchEvent(b)}else{e.clientX=e.pointerX;e.clientY=e.pointerY;var a=document.createEventObject();b=extend(a,e);g.fireEvent('on'+c,b)}return g}function extend(a,c){for(var b in c){a[b]=c[b]}return a}var eventMatchers={HTMLEvents:/^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,MouseEvents:/^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/};var defaultOptions={pointerX:0,pointerY:0,button:0,ctrlKey:false,altKey:false,shiftKey:false,metaKey:false,bubbles:true,cancelable:true};function TestClick(){simulate(document.getElementById('flls').firstChild,'click')};";
                    head.AppendChild(testScript);
                    webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("TestClick");

                    string TestUrl = webBrowser2.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                    if (TestUrl.Equals(expected))
                    {
                        HasSucceeded = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // No test
                    }
                }));
```

The long simulate function is from another StackOverflow answer.  When I type this in the web dev tools console on IE9 it works fine, but this script doesn't work at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDITED]**
What I said below was incorrect. Your syntax is correct, `webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("TestClick")` should do the same job as `webBrowser2.InvokeScript("TestClick")`. I'll try your code and get back here.

<strike>I think the correct syntax should be this:</strike>

```
webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("TestClick()");
```

Note `()` after `TestClick`.

Or you could rather do:

```
webBrowser2.InvokeScript("TestClick");
```

**[EDITED]**
There's something wrong with the HTML originally loaded into the WB, maybe you should include it with your question. The following is just a copy of your code (besides `this.webBrowser2.DocumentText`) and it does work, `TestClick` gets invoked.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser2.DocumentText = "<body><div id=flls><button onclick='alert(true)'>go</button></div></body>";
        this.webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement testScript = webBrowser2.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)testScript.DomElement;
        element.text = "function simulate(g,c){var e=extend(defaultOptions,arguments[2]||{});var b,f=null;for(var d in eventMatchers){if(eventMatchers[d].test(c)){f=d;break}}if(!f){throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported')}if(document.createEvent){b=document.createEvent(f);if(f=='HTMLEvents'){b.initEvent(c,e.bubbles,e.cancelable)}else{b.initMouseEvent(c,e.bubbles,e.cancelable,document.defaultView,e.button,e.pointerX,e.pointerY,e.pointerX,e.pointerY,e.ctrlKey,e.altKey,e.shiftKey,e.metaKey,e.button,g)}g.dispatchEvent(b)}else{e.clientX=e.pointerX;e.clientY=e.pointerY;var a=document.createEventObject();b=extend(a,e);g.fireEvent('on'+c,b)}return g}function extend(a,c){for(var b in c){a[b]=c[b]}return a}var eventMatchers={HTMLEvents:/^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,MouseEvents:/^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/};var defaultOptions={pointerX:0,pointerY:0,button:0,ctrlKey:false,altKey:false,shiftKey:false,metaKey:false,bubbles:true,cancelable:true};function TestClick(){simulate(document.getElementById('flls').firstChild,'click')};";
        head.AppendChild(testScript);
        webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("TestClick");
    }
```